# Jaxb Support for Netbeans 6.5

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, ubuntu, jaxb

I have not been working on java for a long time, and now I am back; so I am sort of noob, particularly with Netbeans. I am using Netbeans 6.5 on Ubuntu. I want to use the Jaxb support to generate Jaxb binding from an XML schema, as documented at http://wiki.netbeans.org/NB6JAXBSample1 . But the document asks to click on "On Project node, New -> JAXB Binding or New -> Other -> XML -> JAXB Binding" but I do not find a "Jaxb binding" option. Do I need to install some plugin or some other thing?

**Edit**

I found that I can use the xjc tool on the command line, which should serve the purpose for now. However a Netbeans wizard will be much useful.

Comment: do you have all the in your link listed prerequisites installed? Also, you don't state that you created a new EJB Module project.

Comment: @Steen For the first question, I am not sure. For the second, I've created a J2SE application project, not EJB.

Comment: @Kumar - You may want to look at the steps again, as step 1 is: Create an EJB project using Java EE 5 version.

Comment: According to http://wiki.netbeans.org/JAXBWizard, the wizard should be available in the following project types: J2SE, EJB, WAR.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the Java web service daveloper pack then just install it. it contains the in-built jaxb library.

Then u need to set the classpath of some of the jar files and then run the following command :

c:/jwsdp> xjc -p  -d